# Java ArrayList serialized file write uses ID and records changing items incorrectly

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, arraylist

I'm trying to use an ArrayList to record the states of an Object as it changes to a file.  I am adding the object to the file each time it changes.  When I look back at the file when the process is complete, it just has multiple copies of the latest values of the object.  I understand that this may be because the OutStream Class uses a single reference to the object.  This would be fine for a data stream but is useless for a file output.  Any ideas how I can solve this?

```
    ArrayList <Reel> reels = new ArrayList<Reel> () ;
    Reel reel = new Reel();
        reel.name = "Default";
        reel.innerDiam = 125;
        reel.outerDiam = 200;
        reel.leftEdge = 150;
        reel.rightEdge = 300;
        reel.saved = false;     //reels = new Reel[100];
    reels.add(reel);
        reel.name = "LRF1A";
        reel.outerDiam = 225;
    reels.add(reel);    
    try { 
        ObjectInputStream reeliStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Reels.ser"));
        reels = (ArrayList<Reel>) reeliStream.readObject();
    } catch (Exception eI) {
    System.out.println("Creating new Reels Repository File");
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream reeloStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Reels.ser"));
            reeloStream.writeObject(reels);
        } catch (Exception eO){
            System.out.println("Failed to created new Reels Repository file.");
        }// try Read Reels
    }//Try Write Reels
    reel = reels.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
ArrayList <Reel> reels = new ArrayList<Reel> () ;
Reel reel = new Reel();
    reel.name = "Default";
    reel.innerDiam = 125;
    reel.outerDiam = 200;
    reel.leftEdge = 150;
    reel.rightEdge = 300;
    reel.saved = false;     //reels = new Reel[100];
reels.add(reel);
    reel.name = "LRF1A";
    reel.outerDiam = 225;
reels.add(reel);
```

you add the same object multiple times in the array list, which makes all entries in the list to point to the same object with the latest values set.

```
ArrayList <Reel> reels = new ArrayList<Reel> () ;
    Reel reel = new Reel();
    reel.name = ...
    // Code
    reels.add(reel);
```

You should create a different object every time:

```
    reel = new Reel(); // NEW OBJECT
    reel.name = ...;
    // Code
    reels.add(reel);
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  I would have to generate a different name for the 'reel' instance each time to avoid conflicts and this would be a problem because other classes set this objects values.  I saw a suggestion somewhere to set  "reel = null", this generates the same conflict problem.  What I would love to do is reel.destroy but java doesn't support that.... hey ho.

Answer (score 0):

After much thinking, searching and experimenting I found a solution to this problem.  All I needed to do was add a clone of the reel object to the ArrayList.  Clones are deep copied and transitory since the actual cloned object only exists in the calling method of the Reels class.

I changed the Reel class declaration to start with

```
public class Reel implements Cloneable{
```

The clone method was added to that class

```
    public Object clone(){
    Reel cloneReel;
    try{
        cloneReel = (Reel) super.clone();
    }
    catch (CloneNotSupportedException e){
        return null;  //never happens !?!
    }
    return cloneReel;
}
```

and the       'reels.add(reel);'      line was changed to

```
reels.add((Reel)reel.clone());
```